# Scale a background SVG non-proportionally and repeating?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

Is there a way to scale an svg background that repeats? For example, a 10x10 pixel svg image that repeats on the X axis, but then the tile can be scaled to 20x10px and repeat across the x-axis using jquery?

This SVG file I uploaded refuses to scale non-proportionally:

```
.myDiv {
   width:100%;
   height:100px;
   background:#eee url(https://svgur.com/i/Hmx.svg) repeat-x;
   background-size: 10% 100%;
 }
```

However, this random SVG I found will scale and repeat:

```
 .myDiv {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:#eee url(http://phrogz.net/svg/tiger.svg) repeat-x;
    background-size: 10% 100%;
 }
```

What's wrong with the first SVG file? Why won't it scale non-proportionally?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Yes. See my post, I'm adding to it.

Comment: @PatrickHennessey Add `width="800"` & `height="323.6"` in first SVG file and remove `viewBox="0 0 800 323.6"` &  `style="enable-background:new 0 0 800 323.6;"` after changes then it will work as 2nd SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The SVG has to have "preserveAspectRatio=none" applied.